# Insert table inside content control with Office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

i'm trying to insert a table inside the content control. Here is my code:

```
function insertTable() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        var cc = range.insertContentControl();
        cc.title = "My Table";
        var values = [["Apple", "red", "round"], ["Banana", "yellow", "long"], ["Pear", "green", "oblong"]];
        context.load(cc);
        return context.sync().then(function () {
                var table = cc.insertTable(3, 3, 'Start', values);
            })
            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            .then(context.sync);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

But i got this error.

```
Error: {"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"InvalidArgument","message":"InvalidArgument","traceMessages":[],"innerError":null,"debugInfo":{"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"InvalidArgument","errorLocation":""},"stack":"InvalidArgument: InvalidArgument\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:211625)\n   at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:249536)\n   at st (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:249623)\n   at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:249443)\n   at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:248029)"}
```

I'm using the beta word api:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Because on api version 1.1 there is not the method `insertTable`. Any idea why it doesn't work? I've seen on the documentation that this method is available on api version 1.3, are they released?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem. It turns out you cannot insert a table in the middle of a paragraph (or in a paragraph that contains something else). When you first add a paragraph, and insert the table in this paragraph you get the desired effect. Please see the code below.

All credits belong to [Cindy Meister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister)

```
function placeTable() {

    Word.run(function (context) {
        var values = [["Apple"]];
        var selectionRange = context.document.getSelection();
        var paragraph = selectionRange.insertParagraph("", "Before");

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                 var table = paragraph.insertTable(1, 1, "Before", values);
                 var contentControl = table.insertContentControl();
            })
            .then(context.sync)
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I got the same error.

However, in my case it was because I provided the insertTable method a column value of less than what the values parameter had.

i.e. my values had three columns and I specified 2 in insertTable.

Hope this helps someone in the future.