# Inserting table at cursor in Word document with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-js, word-addins

**The Problem**

Currently I am developing a Word add-in that provides template functionality for a client. I would like to place a ContentControl that contains a single cell table near the cursor. The Javascript API offers this functionality as can be seen [here (ContentControl class)](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol). Unfortunately, it is possible to place the table before or after the contents of the control, but it is not possible to replace the contents with the table. Whenever I try to achieve the latter, I get a InvalidArgument exception.

Similarly I am unable to directly add a table (without a ContentControl) in the document at the selection. The same exception is thrown. In this case however, it does not matter which location option is specified (before, after, replace the content, etc).

The technology that is used is React and typescript.

---

**Content Control Table**

```
private placeTableControl() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var values = [["Apple"]];

        let selectionRange = context.document.getSelection();
        let contentControl = selectionRange.insertContentControl();

        // This works
        // let table = contentControl.insertTable(1, 1, 'Start', values);

        // This doesn't
        let table = contentControl.insertTable(1, 1, 'Replace', values);

        return context.sync()
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
}
```

---

**Adding Table Without ContentControl**

```
private placeTable() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var values = [["Apple"]];

        let selectionRange = context.document.getSelection();

        // This doesn't work.
        let table = selectionRange.insertTable(1, 1, 'Replace', values);

        // Neither does this.
        //let table = selectionRange.insertTable(1, 1, 'Start', values);

        // Or this.
        //let table = selectionRange.insertTable(1, 1, 'End', values);

        return context.sync()
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
}
```

---

**PARTIALLY SOLVED - Suggestion Cindy Meister**

Cindy Meister suggested that it might have something to do with paragraphs. Tables should be located in a paragraph. Because of my mistake in specifying a simple array instead of a 2D array, I was not able to make it work. This seems to be working now. I will now try to make it work with a content control.

```
private placeTable() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var values = [["Apple"]];

        var selectionRange = context.document.getSelection();

        var paragraph = selectionRange.insertParagraph("", "Before");

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                paragraph.insertTable(1, 1, "Before", values);
            })
            .then(context.sync)
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
}
```

---

**SIMILAR QUESTIONS**

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195018/insert-table-inside-content-control-with-office-js).

Comment: Word can't insert a table in the middle of a paragraph - the Selection *must* be in a paragraph that contains nothing else. Are you certain the Selection is in a valid place? Try inserting a paragraph and put the table in that Range...

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will test it out tomorrow!

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to make this work. I have added the code in the answer. Maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: @CindyMeister it seems you were right! Adding a paragraph allows a table to be added! Thank you! Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: If you've worked out the code, please write the answer. I'm good at Word, but not so good at writing office-js code (yet). If you refer to me in your Answer, that's good enough. Write another comment, "pinging" me, and I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: Thank you again @CindyMeister. I have added the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cindy Meister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister) proposed to first insert a paragraph, since a table cannot be inserted in a paragraph that contains something else. This turned out to be the solution, see the code below. All credits belong to Cindy Meister.

```
private placeTable() {

    Word.run(function (context) {
        var values = [["Apple"]];
        var selectionRange = context.document.getSelection();
        var paragraph = selectionRange.insertParagraph("", "Before");

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                var table = paragraph.insertTable(1, 1, "Before", values);
                var contentControl = table.insertContentControl();
            })
            .then(context.sync)
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Very cleanly written - that helps me with learning this :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

as a second option you can choose to insert the table "after" the selection  and it will create the paragraph for you. check this out: (then you can do table.insertContentControl to wrap it with a content control)

```js
async function insertTable() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        // We need a 2D array to hold the initial table values
        let data = [["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"], ["Tokyo", "Beijing", "Seattle"]];
        let table = context.document.getSelection().insertTable(3, 3, "after", data);
        table.styleBuiltIn = Word.Style.gridTable5Dark_Accent2;

        await context.sync();
    });
}
```